# How to convert org-mode section to html

Tags: org-export, html

There exists `(org-html-export-as-html nil nil t t)` which converts an entire org-mode buffer to another buffer, but is there a way to convert a string in org-mode format to a string in html?

I'm looking to replace the function `org-export-string-as` from [ox-slimhtml](https://github.com/balddotcat/ox-slimhtml), because the package appears to be going away.

Answer (score 1):

`org-export-string-as` should be a built in function of ox.html

You can use it like this:

```
(org-export-string-as "*bold*" 'html)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the contents of a buffer as a string by making the buffer current and then using `buffer-substring`. Something like this:

```el
(with-current-buffer "Org HTML buffer name whatever that is"
   (buffer-substring (point-min) (point-max)))
```

You might want to use `buffer-substring-no-properties` instead if you don't care about text properties.

See the documentation of `with-current-buffer` and `buffer-substring` (or `buffer-substring-no-properties`) for more details: do `C-h f buffer-substring` and similarly for the others.

There are string functions in Emacs (and there is also `s.el`, the "missing" Emacs string library) but if you want to do heavy manipulations, then creating a buffer, putting whatever you want into it, doing all kinds of manipulations and then getting the resulting string out of the buffer with `buffer-substring` is a very general and common idiom (although you'd probably use a temporary buffer in most cases).